# Graphene with SQLAlchemy results in "AssertionError: You need to pass a valid SQLAlchemy Model" with no additional information as to what is wrong

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, graphql

I'm trying to build a FastApi app with a Postgres db and am using SQLAlchemy and Alembic (for handling DB modeling and migrations respectively). And this will be a GraphQL API, so I'm using graphene for that.

Here are my files:-

`models.py`

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, DateTime, Integer, Enum, String, Boolean, JSON
from sqlalchemy.orm import column_property, validates, relationship
from sqlalchemy.sql.schema import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
from config import DEFAULT_AVATARS
from database import Base
import enum

# Status Choices for User's Membership Status 
class MembershipStatusChoice(enum.Enum):
    UI = 'UNINITIALIZED'
    PE = 'PENDINIG'
    AP = 'APPROVED'
    SU = 'SUSPENDED'
# End of Status Choices

# Start of setting up Course status choices
class CourseStatusChoice(enum.Enum):
    DR = 'DRAFT'
    PU = 'PUBLISHED'
    AR = 'ARCHIVED'      
# End of status choices



class AnnouncementsSeen(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'announcements_seen'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = relationship('User', backref='user')
    announcement_id = Column(ForeignKey('announcement.id'), index=True)

class CompletedCourses(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'completed_courses'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    participant_id = relationship('User', backref='user')
    course_id = Column(ForeignKey('course.id'), index=True)

class CompletedChapters(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'completed_chapters'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    participant_id = relationship('User', backref='user')
    chapter_id = Column(ForeignKey('chapter.id'), index=True)
    course_id = Column(ForeignKey('course.id'))
    status = Column(Enum(CourseStatusChoice))
    scored_points = Column(Integer, default=0)
    total_points = Column(Integer, default=0)
    percentage = Column(Integer, default=0)

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    firstname = Column(String(50), default="Uninitialized", nullable=False)
    lastname = Column(String(50), default="User", nullable=False)
    name = column_property(firstname + " " + lastname)    
    email = Column(String(255), nullable=False, unique=True)
    avatar = Column(String(250), nullable=False, default=DEFAULT_AVATARS['USER'])
    institution_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('institution.id'), nullable=False)
    role = Column(String, ForeignKey('user_role.name'), nullable=True)
    title = Column(String(150), nullable=True)
    bio = Column(String(300), nullable=True)


    @validates('email')
    def validate_email(self, key, email):
        if isinstance(email, str):
            return email.lower()
        return email


    membership_status = Column(Enum(MembershipStatusChoice), nullable=False, default='SU')
    chapters = relationship('CompletedChapters', backref='completed_chapters')
    courses = relationship('CompletedCourses', backref='completed_courses')
    announcements = relationship("AnnouncementsSeen", backref='announcements_seen')
    searchField = Column(String(1000))
    active = Column(Boolean, default=True)
    created_at = Column(
        DateTime(timezone=True),
        server_default=func.now()
    )
    updated_at = Column(
        DateTime(timezone=True),
        server_default=func.now(),
        server_onupdate=func.now()
    )


class UserRole(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user_role'
    name = Column(String(50), primary_key=True, unique=True, index=True)
    description = Column(String(500))
    priority = Column(Integer) # Lower the number higher the priority

    def default_permissions():
        return {}

    permissions = Column(JSON, default=default_permissions)
    searchField = Column(String(600))
    active = Column(Boolean, default=True)
    created_at = Column(
        DateTime(timezone=True),
        server_default=func.now()
    )
    updated_at = Column(
        DateTime(timezone=True),
        server_default=func.now(),
        server_onupdate=func.now()
    )
```

`schemas.py`

```
from graphene_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyObjectType
from pydantic import BaseModel

from models import User


class UserSchema(BaseModel):
    title: str
    content: str


class UserModel(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = User
```

`main.py`

```
import graphene
from models import User
from schemas import UserModel
from database import db_session

db = db_session.session_factory()

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):

    all_users = graphene.List(UserModel)
    user_by_id = graphene.Field(UserModel, user_id=graphene.Int(required=True))

    def resolve_all_users(self, info):
        query = UserModel.get_query(info)
        return query.all()

    def resolve_user_by_id(self, info, user_id):
        return db.query(User).filter(User.id == user_id).first()

app = FastAPI()


app.add_route("/graphql", GraphQLApp(schema=graphene.Schema(query=Query)))
```

I have this all in a docker. So I use these commands to make the migrations and run the app:-

```
    "makemigrations": "docker-compose run app alembic revision --autogenerate -m 'New Migration'",
    "migrate": "docker-compose run app alembic upgrade head",
```

The docker command that runs the app is `uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --reload`

But when I make the migrations and migrate and start the app, this is what I get:-

```
app        | INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
app        | INFO:     Started reloader process [1] using statreload
app        | Process SpawnProcess-1:
app        | Traceback (most recent call last):
app        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
app        |     self.run()
app        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
app        |     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
app        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/subprocess.py", line 76, in subprocess_started
app        |     target(sockets=sockets)
app        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 50, in run
app        |     loop.run_until_complete(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
app        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
app        |     return future.result()
app        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 57, in serve
app        |     config.load()
app        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/config.py", line 318, in load
app        |     self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
app        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 22, in import_from_string
app        |     module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
app        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
app        |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
app        |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
app        |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
app        |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
app        |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
app        |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
app        |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
app        |   File "/app/api/./main.py", line 6, in <module>
app        |     from schemas import UserModel, UserSchema
app        |   File "/app/api/./schemas.py", line 12, in <module>
app        |     class UserModel(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
app        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/graphene/utils/subclass_with_meta.py", line 52, in __init_subclass__
app        |     super_class.__init_subclass_with_meta__(**options)
app        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/graphene_sqlalchemy/types.py", line 210, in __init_subclass_with_meta__
app        |     assert is_mapped_class(model), (
app        | AssertionError: You need to pass a valid SQLAlchemy Model in UserModel.Meta, received "<class 'models.User'>".
```

I found these [GitHub issues](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-sqlalchemy/issues/121) that indicate that there may be silent errors that sqlalchemy is giving off that are not showing up in the stack trace. But I'm not able to use that info to precisely pinpoint what is wrong with my model configurations. I tried working out the many to many relationships there and even removing them to see if it fixes it. But it keeps showing the same error. Need help!

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think the error is coming because in main.py you haven't called the meta data.

```
class User(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    """
    User Connection
    """
    class Meta:
        """setting up connection for flow_details"""
        model = models.User
        
        # use `exclude_fields` to exclude specific fields ie "id"
        interfaces = (relay.Node,)

        # fields = "__all__"

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
node = relay.Node.Field()
get_user=SQLAlchemyConnectionField(User.connection)
```

import from graphene import relay as well. You need to set a connection first. When you are calling the resolver its not getting any Sqlalchemyobject to fetch data from

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by commenting a relationship from class definitions like below. Seems to be issue with Class definition and relationship, next I need to look into that.

```
class Department(Base):
    __table_args__ = {"schema":"dbo"}
    __tablename__ = 'graphql_department_temp'
    id = Column(Text, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text)


class Employee(Base):
    __table_args__ = {"schema":"dbo"}
    __tablename__ = 'graphql_employee_temp'
    id = Column(Text, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text)
    # hired_on = Column(DateTime, default=func.now())
    department_id = Column(Text, ForeignKey('department.id'))

    # This section
    #
    # department = relationship(
        # Department,
        # backref=backref('employees',
                        # uselist=True,
                        # cascade='delete,all'))
```